# Command: .../usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8

**Error:**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

1. When i add core data `.xcdatamodeld` ext. file in Project. After
   compilation above error occurs and after deleting `.xcdatamodeld`of
   from project error will not show and compiles successfully.
2. I also checked `Project > Targets > Build Phases`, but there are no
   highlighted red color files.

I tried to clean the project.What is it and how may I know more about it?
Thank you!

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: This error show when compile : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: right click on xcdatamodeld then show in finder check xcdatamodeld file not duplicated or available there .

Comment: There is no any duplicate file of .xcdatamodeld